# Hibernate working with queries

Tags: java, hibernate

Started to learn hibernate. Doing everything by tutorial, but when I try to do simple select, nothing happens. Сan't understand what the problem is.

Logs:

```
мар 28, 2016 12:54:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
мар 28, 2016 12:54:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
мар 28, 2016 12:54:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskboard]
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
мар 28, 2016 12:54:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskboard]
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name="id_user")
private Long id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="login")
private String login;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;
}//get&set
```

Main.java

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    List<User> users = null;

    try {
    session.beginTransaction();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    users = criteria.list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    for (User user: users) {
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskboard</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">1234</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="User" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

static {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder =  new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(cfg.getProperties());

    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return  sessionFactory;
   }
}
```

Comment: put, users.size() into System.out.println() before for loop, and check what you get ?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `nothing happens`?

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens ?

No select query is shown in logs.

Comment: users.size() I get 0.

Comment: @Jaive into database User-table contain data ? if not then definatly you will get users.size() 0, first insert something into database will appear into your code.

Comment: In the console I get the query result, but it is not. When i try to create a table the result is similar (it is not created, no error).

Comment: Of course the table has data.

Comment: @Jaive What is the version of hibernate you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, the newer version of hibernate do not support `<mapping class= .../>` in the hibernate configuration file any longer.

Can you remove that and instead try with

> `cfg.addAnnotatedClass(User.class)` in your `HibernateUtil` static block.

On a different note, you may want to consider using the latest approach of building the `sessionFactory` as `Configuration` way is deprecated. Refer to [Native Bootstrapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#bootstrap-native-sessionfactory) section for more information.

Answer (score 0):

May be nothing in data base for Users table.First Insert some data. Then check.

Comment: This is not an answer, You could've put this as a comment!